# ToggleButton IsChecked trigger

Tags: wpf, triggers, togglebutton

I am writing one application where I have a `ToggleButton` and other few controls on UI.  I want to achieve bellow two things when state of `ToggleButton` is `IsChecked`.

```
1) Hide few controls e.g. button1,button2 etc. in below example
2) Change 'Content' of ToggleButton to 'Show'
```

I can achieve point no 2 but don't know how to access other control and set their properties inside a `Trigger`.  My xaml code is shown below:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="108*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="107*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="96*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="209*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="161*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="133*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ToggleButton x:Name="tg"
                Height="20"
                Width="80"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="2,38,79,49"
                Grid.Row="1">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Content"
                Value="Hide" />
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                   Value="true">
            <Setter Property="{Binding ElementName=Button1,Path=Content}"
                    Value="Show" />
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
  </ToggleButton>
  <Button Content="Button1"
          Height="23"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="45,28,0,0"
          Name="button1"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="75" />
  <Button Content="Button2"
          Height="23"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="38,28,0,0"
          Name="button2"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="75"
          Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Question: When user clicks on toggle button 'tg' I want to hide 'button1','button2' and when state of toggle button changes to un-check again show the button1.

How can I toggle the visibility of button1 with the `ToggleButton`'s `IsChecked` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your resources declare `BoolToVisibilityConverter` as given below:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Then set the visibility of button1 as binding:

```
    <Button Content="Button1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,28,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" 
            Visibility="{Binding ElementName=tg, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
```

Comment: Does that means I have to write this for each and every button that I want to show/hide.  Along with hiding buttons I also want to change width of grid columns.  Actually I am trying to find solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632068/zooming-in-specific-part-of-screen-in-wpf quesion.

Comment: One option could be to put all your buttons/elements inside container and show/hide that container.